# Magento 2.2.5 - How to add the google captcha in checkout page before place order button

Tags: checkout, captcha, recaptcha

Magento 2.2.5 - How to add the google captcha in checkout page before place order button.

I need to show the google captcha in checkout page before place order button.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Magento 2 Google reCaptcha - Invisible CAPTCHA](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha) . And for reference, you can check the [How to add Google reCAPTCHA into Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/how-to-add-google-recaptcha-into-magento-2.html) article.

Comment: but visible acptcha not working

Comment: could you please provide the program and also i need to show only visible captcha

Comment: you mean to say you want customers to type the characters?  Have you followed the article?

Comment: I need show the recaptcha in checkout page before the place order button not visible captcha.
And also i have followed the above article but this extension not working fine

Comment: Have you installed the `Mageplaza_Core` module? As it is required. Or which thing is not working can you add some info.

Comment: You can check its GitHub repo[https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-google-recaptcha] and can find the comment about to add it in any form in FAQ's second question. Let me know if you have any confusion.

Comment: yes i have installed the Mageplaza_Core  module also but this extension show only invisiable captcha in frontend and also visiable captcha in backend..